# Error in Django matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I am calculating property in my Extra model from my second model LeaseExtra.

However it doesn't work for me.

Why I am getting this error?:

> LeaseExtra matching query does not exist.

```
class Extra(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    max_occupants = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    _lease = None


    def _get_total(self):


        from conditions.models import LeaseExtra

        le_dict = LeaseExtra.objects.get(extra_id=self.id, is_active = True )
        if le_dict:
            lease =  le_dict.lease
        else:  
            lease =  0

        self._lease = lease



class LeaseExtra(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    extra = models.ForeignKey(Extra,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    lease = models.ForeignKey(Lease,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_included = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Traceback:

> File
>   "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\rent_unit_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in get_response
>         132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\rent_unit_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>         22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\src\unit\views.py" in extra_available_list
>         163.     extra_list = [obj for obj in extra_list if ( (obj.lease)==0)]
>       File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\src\unit\models.py" in lease
>         166.             self._get_total()
>       File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\src\unit\models.py" in _get_total
>         151.         le_dict = LeaseExtra.objects.get(extra_id=self.id, is_active = True )
>       File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\rent_unit_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py"
>   in manager_method
>         127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Users\PAPA\DEV\rent_unit\rent_unit_venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
>   in get
>         334.                 self.model._meta.object_name
>
> ```
> Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /unit/list/extra/available/
> Exception Value: LeaseExtra matching query does not exist.
> ```

UPDATE:

view

```
    @login_required
def extra_available_list(request):
    EXTEND = "rent_base.html"
    extra_list = ExtraFilter(request.GET, queryset=Extra.objects.all().order_by('-created'))
    extra_list = [obj for obj in extra_list if ((obj.lease)==0)]

    paginator = Paginator(unit_list, 10) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        extra_page = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        extra_page = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        extra_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    #return render(request, 'customer/company_list.html', {'company': company})
    return render(request,'unit/extra_list.html', {'extra': extra_list,'page_extra':extra_page})
```

url

```
url(r'^list/extra/available/$', views.extra_available_list, name="extra_available_list"),
```

Comment: Show us your views.py and urls.py